# How to deploy a war files and mysql database into docker.

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have mysql  image in my docker container and I don't know how to join together with war files

Comment: With `war` file you mean some web application you need to deploy on an application server? Which application server do you normally use?

Answer (score -1):

Each `Docker` image specifies a master process which the state of that process indicates the state of the `Docker` container created from that image. If that process goes down, the container will be stopped.

In your case you're going to have two main processes, `MySQL Server` process and the Application Server process that you are trying to deploy your war files with (say `Tomcat` if you only need a `JSP` / `Servlet` container to deploy your war files).

So i think it's better that you use two `Docker` images. One for `MySQL Server` [(you can use official `MySQL` Docker image)](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and create another `Docker` image for deploying your war files with, which starts from an Application Server `Docker` image like `Tomcat` [(you can extend from Tomcat official image)](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).